# Кодирование названия секции .text

Tags: linux, unix, elf

Почему в elf-файлах названия секций кодируются по-разному? Я видел (так считает парсер), что секция .text может кодироваться как 146 (0x92) и 155 (0x9B). И есть ли где-нибудь описание того, как должны кодироваться названия секций?

Comment: Вероятно, это offset в таблице строк ELF на конкретную строку с именем секции `".text". Читайте https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как было указано в комментариях, это было смещение строки .text в таблице строк